# iOS: xcodebuild: error: The workspace '' does not contain a scheme named ''

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, xcode6

I'm trying to release a Simulator build for Facebook review of my app.

When I run this command I see a scheme called "Roomify":

> ```
> xcodebuild -list
> ```

```
Information about project "Roomify":
    Targets:
        Roomify
        RoomifyTests

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    Schemes:
        Roomify
        RoomApp
```

However, when I try to build it fails telling me the scheme doesn't exist, why so?

> ```
>     >xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.3 -workspace Roomify.xcworkspace/ -scheme Roomify
> ```

```
    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = i386
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.3

    xcodebuild: error: The workspace 'Roomify' does not contain a scheme named 'Roomify'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I used the wrong command to list the schemes in my workspace.

Instead of:

> xcodebuild -list

Do:

> xcodebuild -workspace Roomify.xcworkspace -list