# How to solve xcodebuild: error: The workspace '' does not contain a scheme named '' in jetbrains AppCode

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, appcode

I know there are many similar questions like [iOS: xcodebuild: error: The workspace '' does not contain a scheme named ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592276/ios-xcodebuild-error-the-workspace-does-not-contain-a-scheme-named)

But I am experiencing build error in Jetbrains AppCode.

```
xcodebuild: error: The workspace 'Project.xcscheme' does not contain a scheme named 'Project.xcscheme'
```

Interesting is that XCode builds this project without problem... 
So that's why managing (deleting or autocreate) of scheme didn't helped for Appcode

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I checked out (from Git) also contents.xcworkspacedata

```
Project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

When I changed following lines AppCode was also able to build the project...

funny thing is that XCode was able to handle this.

```
 <Workspace version = "1.0">
    <FileRef
-      location = "self:/Users/xyz/Development/Projects/Project.xcodeproj">
+      location = "self:sdk.xcodeproj">
    </FileRef>
 </Workspace>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem before, but I found the solution.

Open "Manage Schemes" dialog, and find your scheme, then tick the "Shared" checkbox, then xcodebuild works well.

I hope it will help you. Image below shows how to do.

[image]